# Looping IF statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create an IF statement that displays the value '#N/A' in any cell that is blank within a specific range.

I need the range to be from cell A2 to the last row with data in column E. My code is as follows:

```
Dim desiredRange as Range
Set my_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
Set desiredRange = my_sheet.Range("A2:E" & last_row)

On Error Resume Next
For each cell In Range desiredRange.cells
    If cell.Value = "" Then
      cell.Value = "#N/A"
    End If

Next cell
```

I keep getting the Run-time error '1004: Method 'Range' of object' _Global' failed.

Are there any alternative ways of creating an IF statement to make blank cells = #N/A within a dynamic range?

Comment: desiredrange is the range object you wish to search so ' for each cell in Range("desiredrange")' should be 'for each cell in desiredrange'. But you can probably do this quicker and easier using a union.

Comment: You've already set desiredRange to be a Range object, so this exposes range methods and properties of Range. Try `For each cell In desiredRange.cells`.

Comment: Also, move your error handling line so it's before your `FOR` statement.

Comment: thank you for the help! i edited my post with the changes you suggested and tried to run it, but it only works in column B. I would like it work in each cell between columns A and E if possible?

Comment: Comment out the error handler or just delete it and try running it again. I suspect there's an error somewhere but the error handler is suppressing any messages. If there is an error, note the message, then select debug from the resulting message box and note which line the code stops on.

Comment: When I comment out the error handler, the debugger prompts a message saying 'Run-time error '13': Type mismatch'. It highlights the 'If cell.Value = "" Then' as the issue. I've ran the code on a new spreadsheet with no previous code and it works perfectly. I suspect my previous code in the same sub is causing an issue so I'll create a separate sub, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another method using the `Range.Replace` method (*no looping; no if*)

*Note that I check only column E for last row, as you write in your text, and not the `A:E` range, as you have in your code*

```
Option Explicit
Sub text()
    Dim desiredRange As Range, last_row As Long, my_sheet As Worksheet
    Set my_sheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    With my_sheet
        last_row = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        Set desiredRange = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(last_row, 1))
        desiredRange.Replace "", "#N/A"
    End With
End Sub
```

***Note:** If you prefer to have the actual error in the cell, rather than the string representation, change the **replacement** argument to `"=NA()"`*